# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: sqlResultSetMappings

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: sqlResultSetMappings` <br/>
```

I getting this error and unable to fix coz may be this is lack of understanding of hibernate annotation jars.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: sqlResultSetMappings
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.createExtendedMappings(AnnotationConfiguration.java:166)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:254)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1036)
at com.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
at com.view.OrderProcessingAction.<init>(OrderProcessingAction.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:154)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:143)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:113)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:365)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.access$000(DefaultActionInvocation.java:38)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$1.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:83)
```

I have added stacktrace now.

Comment: jars may be outdated.

Comment: hibernate3 , hibernate-annotations-3.2.1.ga.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the proper Hibernate initialization code, this issue is likely an inconsistency in the jar's version.

Although you've detected the cause correctly, I suggest you to print here the whole stacktrace. You can find in the stack trace where exactly the code fails (which class, method and so on). With this information find the relevant jar by the class name. 
You can use jarfinder for this purpose:
[Jarfinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/)

This will let you know which jar is inconsistent with your current hibernate configuration.

Hope this helps

Comment: ok, so it looks like you have an issue with hibernate-annotations jar. Can you download a source code (hibernate is open source) and see whether you have that field there just be on the safe side. Technically the solution will be most likely to update the hibernate in this case

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some fields in your fields

Look under ‘Native queries’ on this link
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/